# How to remove blank canvas pages from draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I created a one page flow-chart with draw.io and printed it.

After opening it again to create a new version, it opened to what I thought was a blank page. There was now page after page of blank canvas, with the project in the lower right corner.

I tried to go to *Document Properties* → **Custom** but that didn't remove the blank pages. There is no obvious way to remove them. The structure chart content is neatly within the one page, so I don't see why it would automatically add more.

The main problem is that I can't print or save because the file is so large my laptop freezes or otherwise stalls when trying to print or save as a pdf.

How can I remove these blank pages?

Comment: This sounds like too specific a case to answer here (or that the answer would help anyone in the future). Just email support@draw.io and share the diagram.

Answer (score 6):

Most likely, you have a component somewhere in the lower right corner which you're not aware of (sometimes, a nasty little text product of a spastic and involuntary click).
Quick solution: Zoom out completely and do a select all. See if anything is selected besides your diagram. Once you delete that unwanted component, all blank pages should disappear.

Answer (score 3):

Though the question is old, this may help someone facing the same issue. For me, one of the outer box layer sizes was not reduced even though the actual box border was small, resizing made the entire content smaller. So, I right-clicked the outer box and selected "Ungroup". Then, magically, the outer extra layer disappeared.